# itertools.groupby returns empty list items, when populated with operator.itemgetter

Tags: python, operator-keyword, python-itertools

I am trying to use the functions groupby and itemgetter in order to re-arrange a sorted list of tuples into groups

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

#initialize a list of tuples
indexed_qualityresults = [(u'moses-R4', 2.0), (u'moses-R4', 3.0), (u'lucy-R4', 3.0), (u'trados-R4', 2.0)]

#group tuples, using as a key the first element of each tuple
groupped_qualityresults = list(groupby(indexed_qualityresults, itemgetter(0)))

#print the key and the respective grouped tuples for each group
print "groupped_qualityresults =", [(a,list(b)) for a,b in groupped_qualityresults]
```

output is

```
groupped_qualityresults = [(u'moses-R4', []), (u'lucy-R4', []), (u'trados-R4', [(u'trados-R4', 2.0)])]
```

As you see, then lists returned for the two first keys of tmy original tuple list are empty, although they shouldn't be.

expected output:

```
groupped_qualityresults = [(u'moses-R4', [(u'moses-R4', 2.0), (u'moses-R4', 3.0)]), (u'lucy-R4', [(u'lucy-R4', 3.0)]), (u'trados-R4', [(u'trados-R4', 2.0)])]
```

Can somebody indentify what's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call `list()` on the `groupby` iterator:

```
#group tuples, using as a key the first element of each tuple
groupped_qualityresults = groupby(indexed_qualityresults, itemgetter(0))

#print the key and the respective grouped tuples for each group
print "groupped_qualityresults =", [(a,list(b)) for a,b in groupped_qualityresults]
```

From the [`itertools.groupby()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.

Turning the output from `groupby()` into a list advances the `groupby()` object.